# Vertically centering text in a div

Tags: html, css, bitcoin

https://satoshifaucet.com/satoshindex

I'm trying to vertically center the text inside the 4 divs with sat, bit, mBTC, and BTC in them. I tried doing

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

on the divs but that isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Also the page loads slow as hell for some reason, must be all the API requests but I'm not sure. Just plain https://satoshifaucet.com loads fast.

Comment: Maybe `line:height: 36px` will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As makshh comment indicates `line-height` will be enough:

```
.smallUnitBox {
    background-color: #29b8ff;
    border-right: 2px solid #2098d4;
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    width: 96px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2098d4;
}

<div class="unitBox">
  <div class="smallUnitBox">sat</div>
  <div class="smallUnitBox">bit</div>
  <div class="smallUnitBox">mBTC</div>
  <div class="smallUnitBox">BTC</div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to remove as it's not needed:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

He means line-height. You could always add a padding-top.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Any idea why the site is so slow to load?

Comment: Looks like PHP I would wager that it's the API request as Chrome inspector does not indicate any problems on the front.